# Reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 internet-related packages

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, internet

My desktop experienced hardware failure and black out, after changing the hardware, the system works, however, it fails to connect to the internet (ethernet), so I want to reinstall the internet module through dpkg, does any know which packages should I install via dpkg?

I tried:

```
$sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED
```

I also tried`ifconfig -a` and basically it only returns info of inet 127.0.0.1

Edit:
The output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` (sorry for the picture cuz there is no internet)
[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as "internet module".

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: hi, already added.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: Screenshot is the only option because no internet. The kernel version is 5.4.0-42-generic

Comment: What hardware did you change? This is a new Ethernet adapter that may need an external driver.

Comment: The motherboard, this is strange, because I have changed motherboard twice, first together with CPU, no problem at all, this time was the motherboard failture during work, so it's more likey to be internal problem. But any way, I may need to reinstall `r8169` driver

Comment: so I reinstalled the `r8169` driver, but still can't access to internet. the `ifconfig -a |grep eth` returns nothing

Comment: How do you install `r8169` driver? It is in-tree and doesn't need installing.

Comment: downloaded from Realtek and compile following the instruction

Comment: I  have found out that in my `/sys/class/net`, there is only `lo`, left, so I can't even check my mac address, this is strange...

Comment: Can you give a link  on what you downloaded? You can download `r8168`, not `r8169` and it is a wrong driver for this adapter.

Comment: https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8169sc-l-software

Comment: I downloaded the second one

Comment: It is a wrong one. You need `r8125`.

Comment: Hi, it solved by installing r8125. Thanks a lot! I upgraded by motherboard from TUF B450m to B550M, is it because the built-in realtek hardware difference between these motherboard or something?

Comment: Exactly, it is another Realtek device.